# Get elements using simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get all the menu items in a website. The code i tried is

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
    $html = dlPage('http://www.homeshop18.com/');
    $htmlpage=new simple_html_dom();
    $htmlpage->load($html);
    $count=1;
    foreach($htmlpage->find('ul#nav') as $li){
            echo $count;
            $count++;
    }
```

There are 10 li element in the ul#nav but the count I get is always 1. why?

Comment: i was running some errands so i wasn't able to follow up in my answer, however you should have stated in your question that you need something inside of those `<li>`'s. thats why i answered earlier with regards to count. im going to delete my answer since you modified your question. anyway try aliens answer

Comment: I think you meant to do: `#nav li` - the why should be obvious if you know css.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to traverse a set of nested `ul` elements, you can use a function like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.homeshop18.com/');
$ulnav = $html->find('ul#nav', 0); // target the ul first

get_nested_lis( $ulnav );

function get_nested_lis( $ul ) {
    # get the children of the ul element
    foreach ($ul->children() as $li) {
        # get the children of each of those li elements
        foreach ($li->children() as $child) {
            # if the element is an 'a', print the contents
            if ($child->tag === 'a') {
                # we have a link
                echo "Link: " . $child->plaintext . "\n";
            }
            # if the element is another ul, call the function on that ul
            elseif ($child->tag === 'ul') {
                get_nested_lis( $child );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the menu on the page that you are trying to traverse is generated by javascript, so if you want to traverse that structure, you will have to copy the source generated by your browser and run your script on that.

Comment: So how can i get the code generated by the browser? I am trying with cURL am in right path?

Comment: You'll need to copy and paste the source from a web browser.

Comment: I need to automate it. Will the Head less browsers give me a solution?